# If I use Flask-SocketIO to implement websockets on the server, do I need a socketio client?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

First important point for me: I want to implement websockets. I do not need the fallback options of socketIO.

I would like "my clients" to implement whatever they want, as soon as they stay to the websockets protocol. Namely something like: *var ws = new WebSocket*.

So.. if the server is Flask-SocketIO, will a simple js WebSocket work?

ADDIONAL NOTES:
Python first!
I am trying to set up a server which will respond only (actually only send) to websockets, no web page associated. (Yes, I am fine with WS and I do not need WSS, in case you ask ;) ).
I had a try on the server side with flask-sockets 
https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets
but it is giving me some problems. Like closing immediately the connection and
beside many similar problems on the web I could not find a solution. Hard to debug too. So before I start developing a new server...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly no, you cannot use a Socket.IO server with plain WebSocket clients. Sorry, that's not what Flask-SocketIO was made for.

(in case this isn't clear, this is the author of Flask-SocketIO speaking)

Comment: @Miguel thanks a lot! an answer from the author is a definition ;)

Comment: @Pipskweak I didn't want to make flask-socketio less awesome, thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to come back. But what was Flask-SocketIO made for? I am asking a bit in a provocative way.. but also because it might solve my problem, if I just see an alternative.

Comment: @mariotti Flask-SocketIO is a Socket.IO server. It was made to connect to Socket.IO clients. Socket.IO is not WebSocket, it is built (optionally) on top of it, so it is higher level.